# template class with static function

Tags: c++

i wanted to create a template class with a static function

```
template <typename T>
class Memory
{
 public:
  template < typename T>
  static <T>* alloc( int dim )
  {
    T *tmp = new T [ dim ];
    return tmp;
  };
}
```

but i will always get

```
int *a = Memory::alloc<int>(5)
```

i dont know what to chance..

```
 »template<class T> class Memory« used without template parameters
 expected primary-expression before »int«
 Fehler: expected »,« or »;« before »int«
```

Comment: i dont compile,the last codebox is the problem :)

Comment: @Tudor: Given that the OP has posted a compiler error message, presumably not!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're templating both the class and the function, when you likely only want to template one of them.

Is this what you mean?

```
template <typename T>
class Memory
{
 public:
  static T* alloc( int dim )
  {
    T *tmp = new T [ dim ];
    return tmp;
  };
}

int *a = Memory<int>::alloc(5);
```

---

Here's a correct version with both:

```
template <typename T>
class Memory
{
 public:
  template <typename U>
  static U* alloc( int dim )
  {
    U *tmp = new U [ dim ];
    return tmp;
  };
}

int *a = Memory<float>::alloc<int>(5);
```

You can remove the outer template if you just want the function to be templated.

Comment: ahh oki, so is it possible to make the funktion with template<typename T> static T* alloc ... ?

Comment: @Roby I don't fully understand what you mean but I've updated the post with another example.